# Создание простых процедур оболочки

Tags: linux, shell

Параметры: имя файла.

Действия: проверить наличие файла в текущем и домашнем каталогах.

- если указанный файл существует в текущем и домашнем каталогах, то он удаляется из домашнего;
- если существует только в текущем каталоге, то перемещается в домашний;

в результате проверок формировать соответствующее сообщение.

помогите,пожалуйста,не получается

Comment: @Natasha А что конкретно не получается?

Comment: @Natasha, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

home=~

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "нужен ровно один параметр"
  exit 1
fi

file="$1"

if [ -f "${file}" -a -f "${home}/${file}" ]; then
  echo "файл есть в обоих каталогах"
  echo "файл удаляется из домашнего каталога"
  rm "${home}/${file}" 
elif [ -f "${file}" -a ! -f "${home}/${file}" ]; then
  echo "файл есть только в текущем каталоге"
  echo "файл перемещается в домашний каталог"
  mv "${file}" "${home}/"
fi
```